# Get duplicates from non query with unique records

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following query and can't understand why I get two duplicates(two records with duplicates) although all records in both tables, a and b, are unique, rest of records look good except these two duplicates:

```
 SELECT    code,
           object_id,
           prod_date
        FROM DAY_STATUS a
 INNER JOIN
 (
 SELECT    o.geo_code, 
           o.OP_FCTY_1_CODE, 
           o.object_id,                    
           o.code
           c.dt as prod_date                    
        FROM
           ov o, 
           FCTY_CLASS_1 c, 
           (select ls.*, lead(dt) over (order by dt) ldt from last_status ls) s
             WHERE  
                     o.op_fcty_1_id = c.object_id
              AND    o.object_id = s.object_id
              AND    s.dt <= c.dt 
              AND    (c.dt < s.ldt or s.ldt is null) 
              AND    s.status = 'ACT'
              AND    c.production_day BETWEEN o.DAYTIME AND o.end_date
              AND    c.production_day = '01-Jan-19'
 ) B  
 ON a.object_id=b.object_id
 AND a.prod_date = '01-Jan-19'
```

Thanks,
S

Comment: you have to share sample data of two tables

Comment: all records are the same in both tables except the B table has more records as it has additional status in addition to 'ACT'.

Comment: duplicate creation only possible if you have the same object_id multiple times  either table a or table b

Comment: `B` is an inline view involving a join.  What is the source of your confidence that it does not have duplicate rows, or at least duplicate-enough rows?  Note that exact duplication of a whole row of `B` is not necessary for the overall query to produce duplicate rows.

Comment: I checked multiple times, all is unique.

Comment: @John Bollinger: I separately run query B and it always gives me unique records.

Comment: @John Bollinger:  I'm not sure I understand this "Note that exact duplication of a whole row of B is not necessary for the overall query to produce duplicate rows", what do you mean?

Comment: @JoeGreen, If two rows of `B` have the same `object_id` but differ in some other column then they are not duplicates of each other, but if other details line up correctly then they could lead to the overall query producing duplicate rows.

Comment: @John Bollinger, I checked duplicates for object_id in B and they don't exist, all object_id is unique.

Comment: @JoeGreen, as Zaynul already said, if the overall query presented produces duplicate rows then there must be duplicate `object_id` values in at least one of `a`, `b`.  If you are correct that there are none in `b`, then they must be in `a`.

Comment: That's what I'm confused, I really can't find duplicates object_id in both tables :(, doesn't make any sense!!

Comment: @JoeGreen the most reasonable conclusion would be that you're not seeing things as they actually are.  There are too many ways that could happen for us to guess here, which is why we typically ask for a [mre].  Who knows, the process of producing one might lead you to find a solution for yourself.

Comment: @JoeGreen Convert all date values to datetime if they are not just date strings. Strings compare differently than datetimes.